# Display a std::string from index i to the end of the string

Tags: c++, string, char

For example:

```
char s[]="abcde";
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
          cout<<s+i<<endl;
```

Output:

```
abcde
bcde
cde
de
e
```

And this doesn't ruin the char array.

What I want to ask for help is, is there another way we can do that with the `std::string` class?

Comment: use `std::string::substr`

Comment: You can still use `std::string::c_str() + i`.

Comment: Never use a call of `strlen` as condition in a loop while iterating on string. You do extra work, it makes complexity _O(n^2)_ instead of _O(n)_.

Comment: @alexolut: Never use _the same_ call of `strlen`. Microsoft sometimes uses a pattern where a list of strings is represented as one contiguous character array, and the list is terminated by an empty string. The loop you need there is `for(char* s = begin; strlen(s) ; s+=strlen(s)+1)` This is clearly O(n*m) because you have O(n) strings of length O(m).

Comment: @MSalters not enough clearly as I see, because of call of `strlen` twice on iteration.

Comment: @alexolut: True, but `O(n*m*2)` is identical to `O(n*m)`. That said, you can optimize it: `size_t len; for(char* s = begin; len = strlen(s) ; s+=len+1)`

Comment: @MSalters Agreed. My first sentence was about iterating on string **by symbols**. In your case - that's loop on list of strings by strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cheap and nasty way, closest to what you already have: use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

```
std::string const s{"abcde"};
char const *c = s.c_str();
for (std::size_t i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << c+i << '\n';
```

The more `string`-like way is to use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
std::string const s{"abcde"};
for (std::size_t i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << s.substr(i) << '\n';
```

Note that the second approach does involve allocating memory for the new `string` every time, but I think here the benefit of clarity (using a function specifically named and designed for what you are trying to do), and avoiding raw pointers (often a cause of confusion for beginners) both outweigh the performance (non-)issue here.

---

A more modern approach that combines the clarity of using specific C++ components designed for what you want, with avoiding extra allocations, is to use [`std::experimental::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view), which is designed to wrap an existing string of characters:

```
std::string const s{"abcde"};
std::experimental::string_view sv{s};
for (std::size_t i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << sv << '\n';
    sv.remove_prefix(1);
}
```

[`std::experimental::string_view::remove_prefix`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view/remove_prefix) does what you might expect: shrinks the view of the string it is wrapping at the front, by the number specified.

`string_view` is not technically part of The Standard yet, so I don't really recommend it for production use, since you won't get good cross-platform support. But it's quite fun to learn about. You might consider the very similar (not coincidentally) component, [`boost::string_ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html) to be production quality.

---

Also, please reconsider your use of what are often considered bad practices: [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html) (those are links to explanations).